# Jetty 9 Websockets repeating timeout exceptions from disconnected clients

Tags: websocket, jetty

While developing a web application, I have come across what appears to be a bug with Jetty's WebSocket connection management. I'm wondering if anyone has had the misfortune to encounter this problem, and if so, how they have worked around, or avoided this issue.

The problem I am experiencing is in three parts:

1. Jetty doesn't recognize the client WebSocket is closed (I do not get
   an onClose event, and the WebSocketConnection.isConnected() returns
   true). Note that I am pinging the client every second, but only the 
   first ping fails: other pings after the first don't return a result 
   (failed or success).
2. All messages from the time the client ACTUALLY closed build up, and
   do not fail until 5 minutes after after connection has been severed,
   dumping all the pending messages to the console with a
   java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException
3. These (failed) pending messages do not get cleared.  All messages sent to a
   disconnected client, for each WebSocket connection the Jetty server
   has ever gotten, dump an InterruptedByTimeoutException every 5
   minutes.

In the short term, my server can still accept new connections, and my application can still limp along.  However, as you can imagine, once enough of these messages build up, the thread reporting all of the timeouts eats up execution time, and new connections wont be accepted, HTTP, WebSocket or otherwise.

I have tested this mostly with Jetty 9.0.0.M2, but 9.0.0.M3 appears to have the same problem.  For those interested, here are my specific steps to reproduce:

1. Open a web page that creates a WebSocket connection to your Jetty 9
   server. (It may or may not be relevant to point out my WebSocket is
   opened from within a WebWorker).
2. Once Jetty recognizes the connection, from Jetty, begin pinging the
   client every second and log the result.
3. Close the tab or browser your client WebSocket page is running in.
4. Observe only one ping fails.  Further pings don't log success or
   failure.  Also observe you don't get an onClose event.
5. Wait 5 minutes and watch your Jetty Console explode with the
   following exception for every ping or message that never finished:

2013-01-12 19:39:52.747:WARN:oejwci.FrameBytes:Timer-3: failed(null)
java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.TimerScheduler$SimpleTask.run(TimerScheduler.java:88)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: The Timeout mechanism for WebSockets has been ripped out for M5 (due out soon), and it is in the process of being replaced with a smarter sweep mechanism.

Comment: Neat.  Do you know of a work around for the time being?